# How to dump temporary MySQL table into a file?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

Is there a way to create a dump/export/save a temporary MySQL table into a file on disk(.sql file that is, similar to one that is created by mysqldump)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I did not read the question properly the first time around...  at any rate, the best I can think of is using the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statement, like this:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'result.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM temp_table;
```

This does have many limitations thought, for instance, it only dumps the raw data without including the field headers.  The other thing I found that may or may not be of use is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement.  If you can find some way of combining the output from these two statements, you may be able to get a proper "dump" file as produced by my command below.

---

You should be able to use the `mysqldump` application:

```
mysqldump --databases temptable > file.sql
```

This will dump the table with `CREATE` decelerations.

Comment: Temp table only exists within the scope of connection, hence this won't work.

Comment: Be aware that SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE requires a specific permission be given to the user.

Comment: can someone explain where the file is created? it certainly was not on the current working directory where I was

Comment: This needs to manage the 'insert' statement in the output file. Clearly doesn't answer the OP's question because this only says how to do a comma delimited CSV file, which is not the same as a mysql dump.