# Finding duplicates and appending arrays to an array with millions of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I've got about 2-5 million arrays to search each day and I'm trying to weed out the duplicates but it's taking quite a long time to search through them and as the object grows it's taking longer and longer. I don't know the array internals to PHP and instead of cracking into the codebase I was hoping someone could give me some pointers. This is the gist of the main loop.

```
$duplicates = array();

foreach ($records as $record) {
    $duplicates = $this->increment_field($duplicates, $record,'id');
}
```

And it generates an array of $duplicates. The work is done in this function.

```
public function increment_field($placeholder_array, $record, $field_name) {

    if (isset($record[$field_name])) {
        if (!isset($placeholder_array[$record[$field_name]])) {
            $placeholder_array[$record[$field_name]] = array($record);
        } else {
            $placeholder_array[$record[$field_name]][] = $record;
        }
    }

    return $placeholder_array;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to optimize the performance would be greatly appreciated.

Example of the incoming data is:

```
$record = array(
 "id" => 123456678,
 "employee_first_name" => "Jane",
 "employee_last_name" => "Doe",
 "manager_first_name" => "John",
 "manager_last_name" => "Doe",
 "office_id" => 1234,
 "created_at" => '2018-11-29 07:59:02',
 "client_ip_address" => 2130706433,
 "server_ip_address" => 2130706532,
);
```

The system generates a CSV file for output and analysis in this format.

```
id,office_id,created_at,client_ip_address,server_ip_address,original_id
123456678,1234,'2018-11-29 07:59:02',2130706433,2130706532,123456678
123456679,1235,'2018-11-29 08:59:02',2130706433,2130706532,123456678
123456680,1236,'2018-11-29 09:59:02',2130706433,2130706532,123456678
123456681,1237,'2018-11-29 10:59:02',2130706433,2130706532,123456678
123456682,1238,'2018-11-29 11:59:02',2130706433,2130706532,123456678
123456683,1239,'2018-11-29 12:59:02',2130706433,2130706532,123456678
```

Comment: How do you identify as a duplicate?

Comment: At least use reference  increment_field(&$placeholder_array...

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does `increment_field` do? What do you mean by 2-5 million arrays?

Comment: Can you give examples of the data? Also, multiple threads could speed this up.

Comment: An example of input and output be better.

Comment: If the data is coming from a database, do the work there so there's no need to run the loop over millions of records.

Comment: As @Bryan points out, there's several reasons a database is more suited for this, but it appears to be a CSV. [No problem!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238470/451969) Not to mention doing the inserts would allow you to control the action `ON DUPLICATE` as well. Or look for duplicates: `SELECT DISTINCT columnName, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tableName HAVING cnt > 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a function is killing the performance. You are duplicating the array when you don't need to. If you move that code inline it'll crush. I tested it with 10 million 1 MB arrays and I was able to complete the analysis in 2 mins when the code was inline and it's still running when I tested the code in a function. It's not exactly what you're looking for but if you need the performance this is a solution. As Larry Walls says, "There's more than one way to do it."

```
$duplicates = array();

foreach ($records as $record) {

    if (isset($record['id'])) {
        if (!isset($duplicates[$record['id']])) {
            $duplicates[$record['id']] = array($record);
        } else {
            $duplicates[$record['id']][] = $record;
        }
    }
}
```